# Asp.Net Core 2.1 Static Files

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core

Normally we are link the `css` with like

```
<environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/IndexCss.css" />
    </environment>
```

But can i just link the folder ? Cus have too many css need to link ...
Or any suggustion

Comment: No you can't load a whole folder. You must make a link for each file.

Comment: @ADyson With ASP.NET Core, your comment is not accurate.

Comment: @Serj Sagan I know that but the question asked specifically about creating a link to the folder directly. I agree that bundling is a good solution but it will still potentially generate lots of link tags in the HTML (depending how you configure it) and even then it's still a link to a generated file, not a folder. So yeah maybe I was being a bit too narrow but in terms of the strict semantics of the question I was correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ASP.NET Core MVC` comes with a built in bundler and minifier so that many `CSS` files can become one, also does the same for `JavaScript` files.

Just create a file called `bundleconfig.json` at the root of the project with content like this:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
      "~/css/*.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "~/js/*.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio